facing "Unparsable Response" while making any Python SDK function calls in Zoho Catalyst advancedio function
I am facing an error while using the Python SDK of Zoho Catalyst. I have created an Advancedio function and performed operations with ZCQL, but it seems there is an error in the SDK while parsing the response. I am closely following the instructions from the supported docs(https://docs.catalyst.zoho.com/en/sdk/python/v1/cloud-scale/data-store/get-table-meta/)
but getting the below error:
CatalystAPIError("{'code': 'UNPARSABLE_RESPONSE', 'message': 'unable to parse the response json'}")
I tried quitting the server and re-starting. But, it doesn't help
I tried quitting the server and re-started. But, it doesn't help

Update your Catalyst Python SDK version to 1.0.0rc2 in your requirements.txt file of your Python function and then test your application by running the catalyst serve command to solve this issue.
